# MVC EditorFor only rendering single property, not EditorTemplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, editorfor, editorfortemplate

Got some issues with EditorFor and I can't understand the behaviour.

I have a list of objects where I want to render an editor template based on that list.

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/26069912 the EditorFor should render the template for each object.

```
  public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

The template

```
@model EditForTest.Models.Person

Name
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)</td>
Phone
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PhoneNumber)</td>
```

In the view I got a view model containing a list of persons. When I use

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Persons)
```

the template is not rendered and somehow the first property is rendered on the page.

Comment: Have you named the template correctly? - `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Person.cshtml`

Comment: Would Persons happen to be be a List of Person objects? I am pretty sure an editor template will not work like that. You would have to loop over the list manually and call the EditorFor.

Comment: I'd rather a `PartialView ` instead

Comment: @StephenMuecke That was my problem, my template was not located in the correct folder. Once i moved it the fields were render properly for each object in the list.

Answer (score 0):

As @StephenMuecke mentioned I had a problem with my editor template.
Once the template was moved to the correct path /Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Person.cshtml the editor was rendered properly.