# ASP.NET MVC form submit data can't bind to the model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC form where I am posting this data from JS over to this controller. I can't get this data to bind to the model. The current model is looking for the hidden field with a name of `PollingResponse[int]`. I am not sure why this is not binding is it something with the model, any help would be great.

View

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <input id="PollingResponse_1__QuestionType" name="PollingResponse[1].QuestionType" type="hidden" value="LongAnswerText">
    <input id="PollingResponse_1__MeetingPollingQuestionId" name="PollingResponse[1].MeetingPollingQuestionId" type="hidden" value="1">
    <input id="PollingResponse_1__MeetingPollingPartsValuesId" name="PollingResponse[1].MeetingPollingPartsValuesId" type="hidden" value="1">

    <input class="form-control p-0 k-input" id="PollingResponse_1__Value" name="PollingResponse[1].Value" data-role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" autocomplete="off" style="width: 100%;">
</div>
```

js serialize data

```
PollingResponse%5B1%5D.QuestionType=LongAnswerText&PollingResponse%5B1%5D.MeetingPollingQuestionId=1&PollingResponse%5B1%5D.MeetingPollingPartsValuesId=1&PollingResponse%5B1%5D.Value=klllllllllllllllllllll&PollingResponse%5B16%5D.QuestionType=MultipleChoice&PollingResponse%5B16%5D.MeetingPollingQuestionId=16&PollingResponse%5B72%5D.MeetingPollingPartsValuesId=72
```

Model

```
public class PollingResponseFormViewModel
{
    public List<Response> PollingResponse { get; } = new List<Response>();
}

public class Response
{
    public int MeetingPollingPartsValuesId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionType { get; set; }
    public int MeetingPollingQuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: see if this helps you to solve the problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69906047/serializing-form-subgroups-for-ajax-submission-to-asp-net-mvc/69981577#69981577) also pay attention to ajax section

Comment: Looks pretty similar

Comment: Editor Templates can be useful in these scenarios where you are rendering and posting/binding collections. The framework will ensure the values are rendered out with the correct indexing i.e. PollingResponse[1].QuestionType, PollingResponse[2].QuestionType. Then when you serialize and post these back to the server, they bind without any issues. An example can be found here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26069912/5296627